# SQL Server : Trace won't create file

Tags: sql, sql-server, trace

I'm trying to start using SQL Trace and I am running into "Access Denied" errors when using the following:

```
exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 0, N'C:\Users\USER$\Desktop\SQLTrace', @maxfilesize, NULL
```

if (@rc != 0) goto error

I have tried UNC path and local, I am using an admin account to login to Mgmt Studio, what component am I missing? I have tried saving locally and to a remote client.

Comment: Is the server remote, or is it installed on your local machine?

Comment: The server is remote I am using local Mgmt Studio

Comment: The trace file will be created **in the filesystem** of your **remote server** (not in the file system of your local machine!) - does that server have a `C:\users\.....` directory??

Comment: Yes it does have that path locally on the server....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears for whatever reason I had to point the location to here for it to work:

C:\Users\Public\Desktop

Regardless of which account I used for SSMS... Definitely permission related, but as I am Admin for windows and SQL not sure where root cause lies..

Comment: Part of the issue, at least on a local workstation (e.g. your laptop) is that, if you've installed SQL Server, it's using a "local service" account (like `NT Service\blah`), which typically does *not* have permissions to write to most user-folder locations.  Except of course Public.

Answer (score 1):

It's not what permissions your account has, it's whether or not the account that is used to start SQL Server service has write permissions to that folder. Please check that first.  See [sp_trace_create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190362.aspx) doc:

> For sp_trace_create, the SQL Server service account must have Write permission on the trace file folder. If the SQL Server service account is not an administrator on the computer where the trace file is located, you must explicitly grant Write permission to the SQL Server service account.

Comment: Ok, do you know what all the services are the SQL uses that will need admin permissions? I have tried MSSQLSERVER (adding Admin NTFS permissions on the DEV box only), and that hasn't worked yet...

Comment: It's the account that starts the MSSQLServer service.  You are going to have to do a little more debugging that just that - did you try logging into the server with the same account, and verifying that you can write to folder C:\Users\USER$\Desktop\SQLTrace?  You could also try executing xp_cmdshell, and see if you can create a folder, or access the same folder.  Either way, it will come down to a permission issue with the account.

Comment: Yep I'm sure that's a permission issue, however I am logging into the Dev box with an Admin account, using that same admin account to open SSMS. I have also been able to create and delete with that same account in windows, that's why this is frustrating... trying to determine exactly where the permission issue is....

Comment: the account used to open SSMS has nothing to do with the account used to start the MSSQLServer service.  Open SQL Server Configuration Manager, go to SQL Server services, open the SQL Server service and see what Log On account is used.

Comment: Greg, I think you misunderstand, I only stated both to illustrate that I have tried both. I know that SSMS is logging in with Admin account as it uses windows authentication and my account is Admin. It shows my login in the username/password box when logging in....

Comment: SSMS <> SSCM.  You need to go to SSCM (SQL Server Configuration Manager).

Answer (score 0):

Running SQL Server Management Studio as an administrator on your local machine will not give administrative permissions on the remote machine. Try to Remote Desktop into the server as an administrator and run the query there.

Comment: I have remoted into the server and run the Mgmt studio on that server as admin and still get same error...

Comment: Are you using windows authentication or a SQL login to login to Management Studio?

Comment: Is USER$ the same account that you are logging into over RDP, and is it the same account with which you are logging into SSMS? Is there already a file on your desktop named SQLTrace.trc?

Comment: Yes, and I can create a document there outside of SSMS, so I am confused on what "access" is being denied. I am assuming it is on the SSMS side as if it were NTFS I would not be able to navigate or create in that same folder. I am wondering if I need to check the permissions associated with my login on the SP_Trace_Create... Does anyone know where that resides?